# Changed name of app now not recognizing my AndroidManifest file

Tags: java, android

I recently changed the name of my app and now when I try to run it the program won't let me run it because it can't recognize my android manifest file. I really need help this is a project due soon. It puts all my code in red too. IT ALSO SAYS MY URI IS NOT REGISTERED.

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: did you change pkg name in manifests file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you do a clean-rebuild after changing your app's name?

Comment: Check package= in Manifest, check applicationId in build.gradle

Comment: yes i did change it

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the *application ID* in `build.gradle` you should have no problem. If you changed *package name* in `AndroidManifest.xml` you will have problems.

The package name from manifest is used as directory where `R` class is generated. `BuildConfig` is also generated in this package. When you change package name you also have to update all the import statements. You don't want this.

The application ID is the actual identifier that's used when the app is installed on a device or uploaded to Google Play.

Update application ID and return package name to its original value. You should be able to build again.

Comment: If it says your configuration is incorrect, then how can we help if we don't know the original and the new configuration? Please update your question and post your build.gradle files and *exactly* what you changed.

Comment: I changed the app's name on finder.

Comment: I don't know what "changed on finder" is. Perhaps you should undo that. At this point I'm not sure if my answer helps you, I don't fully understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you:
- Using `Refactor -> Apply All`(best way)

- check on `build-grandle` and the `AndroidManifest.xml` is showing the same name?
- do `Build->Clean Project` and `Build->rebuild Project`
- Re run

it's work on me..